# Natural parameterization of a curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I need the natural parameterization or a geodesic curve contained in the surface $z=x^2+y^2$, that goes through the origin, with x(s=0)=0, y(s=0)=0, dx/ds (s=0)=cos(a) and dy/ds(s=0)=sin(a), with "a" constant, expressed as a function of the arc length, i.e., I need $r(s)=r(x(s),y(s))$.

Thank you very much!

Eva

Comment: There are many, many curves on this surface passing through the origin. Do we get to pick one at random?

Comment: I need the curve with x(s=0)=0, y(s=0)=0, dx/ds (s=0)=cos(a) and dx/ds(s=0)=sin(a), with a constant, thank you!

Comment: There are still infinitely many such curves. All you've done is specified the direction it is traveling as it passes through 1 point. Away from that point a curve can do anything.

Comment: This curve has to be a geodesic, does this add relevant information?

Comment: Considerably. Do you know what a geodesic is?

Comment: Also can you think of a coordinate system that might work better for this problem than cartesian?

Comment: Thank yoy for the comments. Any change in the coordinate system can be valid, can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I am trying to, but I will not just give you the answer. You need to figure this out yourself, or there is no point in doing it. So far I've given you three pushes in the right direction: (1) pay attention to *all* information about the problem, which it took two attempts before you finally gave the critical bit you'd left off (2) Review the properties of that critical bit ("geodesic") and try to understand how it affects this problem (3) a certain different set of coordinates would be *very* useful here. So far, you've not picked up on (2) or (3).

Comment: I have tried with the parametrization x=r*cos(a), y=r*sin(a), z=r^2. That works fine to get the geodesic, but I can not get the natural parametrization with s as the arc length. It seems that I have to make a different one, but I can not figure out which, any clue?

Comment: So $ds = \sqrt {dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2} = \sqrt {1 + 4r^2} dr$. This is a workable integral.

Comment: The solution of this integral is s = (1/4)*ln⁡(2*r+sqrt(1+4*r^2))+(1/2)*r*sqrt(1+4*r^2), which is an equation in which I can not calculate r as a function of s to perform the natural parametrization. This is the reason of my question, maybe another parametrization could work, buy it does not happen to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have $$ s(r) = \int_0^r\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt$$
set $t = \frac 12\sinh u,\ dt = \frac12\cosh u\,du$
$$s(r) = \frac12\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}2r}\cosh^2u\,du\\=\frac14\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}2r}1 + \cosh 2u\,du\\=
\frac{\sinh^{-1}2r}{4} +\left.\frac18\sinh 2u\right|_0^{\sinh^{-1}2r} \\= \frac{\sinh^{-1}2r}{4} + \frac14\sinh(\sinh^{-1}2r)\cosh(\sinh^{-1}2r)\\=\frac{\sinh^{-1}2r}{4} + 2r\sqrt{1+4r^2}\\
=\frac14\ln(2r + \sqrt{1+4r^2})+ 2r\sqrt{1+4r^2}$$
I agree that finding a nice expression for $r(s)$ from inverting the above fomula does not look possible.

But consider this. Suppose you find some other parametrization in terms of some $t$, so you know $(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ and can solve $$s(t) = \int \sqrt{\dot x^2 + \dot y^2 + \dot z^2}\,dt$$ and invert the result to get $t(s)$. But since the curve is on the surface, $z = r^2$, so $$r(s) = \sqrt{z(t(s))}$$
which by presumption are all known functions. That is, to reparametrize so as to have a nicely invertible arclength function *is to invert the function of $r$ above. If you can do one, you can do the other.

I rather doubt that $r(s)$ has an expression in terms of elementary functions, even though $s(r)$ does. I could be wrong,but generally when you find $r$ occurring both inside a transcendental function and outside it, the inverse is not going to elementary. And if that is the case here, then *no other parametrization* will give you a better result. They can be easy to determine with respect to $r$ or with respect to $s$, but not with respect to both.

But all is not lost. While actually finding a nice expression for the inverse may not be possible, $s'(r) > 0$, so the function is $1-1$ and therefore invertible. You can define $$f(r) =\frac{\sinh^{-1}2r}{4} + 2r\sqrt{1+4r^2}$$ and then $$r = f^{-1}(s)$$.
This is not just playing with notation. For specific $s$, there are numerous techniques for calculating $f^{-1}(s)$ to any desired accuracy, including developing Taylor series for it. And this is no worse than calculating most functions elementary expressions.

"$r = f^{-1}(s)$" may not be the solution you wanted, but it is still a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Please let me ask you one last question: are the "meridian" (i.e., intersections with vertical planes) geodesics the only ones that go through the origin?

Comment: There is one through the origin in every direction, so yes, they are all the geodsics.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your help.